# php check database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a point system. in the system now I got so when people buy 1 ticket for 5 points they lose it from MySQL. But I don't know how to make a limit. Now people can buy infinite points and it don't stop. the only thing that happens is that they get -10 points(example). I want to make so if they got 0-4 points they can't buy a ticket. The code I use:

```
<?php
session_start();
//=============Configuring Server and Database=======
$host        =    'localhost';
$user        =    'root';
$password    =    '';
//=============Data Base Information=================
$database    =    'login';

$conn        =    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Server Information is not Correct'); //Establish Connection with Server
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

//===============End Server Configuration============

//=============Starting Registration Script==========


$username    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtusername']);

//=============To Encrypt Password===================

//============New Variable of Password is Now with an Encrypted Value========


$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-5) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
mysql_query($insert);

// other codes

$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `lodd` = (`lodd` +1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
mysql_query($insert); 

 mysql_query($insert); 


header('location: succes.php');
?>
```

here are the codes where add 1 ticket and subtract 5 point:

```
$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-5) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
mysql_query($insert);

// other codes

$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `lodd` = (`lodd` +1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
mysql_query($insert); 

 mysql_query($insert);
```

Comment: don't use mysql_ use mysqli_ or PDO instead. Also why don't you just make a select to check their points, if their point value is OK you do the UPDATE, if not, display an error.

Comment: what u mean by this `if they got 0-4 points` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-5) WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `points` >= 5";
```

And then check if the row has been affected with **[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)** as suggested above. If the row was affected, that means the user had 5 or more points.

Comment: i dint quit understnad, the point didnt move when i said that i had 4 point but the lodd steel kept going